# web.DataModel is missing odoo11

Tags: javascript, odoo-10, odoo-11

I'm changing odoo 10 module to odoo 11.I'm facing problem for missing dependency web.DataModel. How can i convert the following code to odoo 11 version.

```
 var temp = {
       'partner_id': client['id'],
       'coupon_pos': cp.code,
          };
 new Model('partner.coupon.pos').call('update_history', 
 ['',temp]).done(function (result) {
     // alert("result")
     var applied = self.pos.applied_coupon;
     var already_used = false;
     for (var j in applied) {
     if (applied[j]['partner_id'][0] == client['id'] &&
         applied[j]['coupon_pos'] == order.coupon_status['code']) {
         applied[j]['number_pos'] += 1;
         already_used = true;
         break;
     }
   }
   if (!already_used) {
      var temp = {
          'partner_id': [client['id'], client['name']],
          'number_pos': 1,
          'coupon_pos': order.coupon_status['code']
       };
       self.pos.applied_coupon.push(temp);
    }
 });
self.gui.close_popup();
```

Answer (score 2):

In v10 **web.DataModel** is used for calling py method in js but it is deprecated in odoo v11. If you want to call any py method in js file you need to use **`_rpc`** method. For example:

```
this._rpc({
                model: 'model.name',
                method: 'method_name',
                args: [arguments],
            })
            .then(function(result) {
                //custom code
            });
```

By this way you can convert v10 js code to v11.